# I want to get data related to date using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make query that if i have no date into request so otherwise data should be shown of current date please help me thanks.

**Controller**

```
          VehicleTask::where('vehicle_id', $this->driver)
            ->whereDate('date', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->orWhere('date',$request->date)
            ->get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimize Version

```html
$date = $request->date ?? Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
VehicleTask::where('vehicle_id', $this->driver)
            ->whereDate('date', $date)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
VehicleTask::where('vehicle_id', $this->driver)
    ->when($request->has('date'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->whereDate('date', $request->date);
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereDate('date', today());
    })
    ->get();
```

Or

```
$date = now(); # or Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($request->has('date')) {
    $date = $request->date;
}
VehicleTask::where('vehicle_id', $this->driver)
    ->whereDate('date', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->orWhere('date', $date)
    ->get();
```